# iOS syncing error 0xE8000004 when syncing big in-house app via iTunes

Tags: ios, in-house-distribution

I have a very large IPA file for an enterprise app, when trying to sync via iTunes I get this error, mac or PC, it doesn't matter.

The app installs and runs fine from Xcode, but the IPA is 6.7GB.  I could not find any size restriction guidelines except the 2GB app store limit, and iTunes doesn't complain about the app size but it will not sync the file.

All I can find on this error is various USB connectivity issues, the app runs fine if not installed via iTunes but through Xcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is more likely to come up for large files (because there's more time to fail) but there's nothing wrong with your app.  It's an issue syncing data.

I'm assuming you've looked at the Apple support article [iOS: Unknown error containing '0xE' when connecting to a Windows PC](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS3221).

If that doesn't resolve the issue, can you open up your device console and post relevant device logs from during the sync?

Comment: I think iTunes just can't handle files larger than 4GB, I was able to install the app via the iPhone Configuration Utility.